# Php Session displaying the error message

Tags: php, html

i am using two webpage in menu.php i am not able to get the detail of session variable it will display undefined index.

### controller.php

```
       $info = mysql_fetch_array( $data );  
       session_start();
       // store session data
       $type="$info[TYPE]";
       $no="$info[NO]";

       $_SESSION['type']=$type;
       $_SESSION['no']=$no;
   echo "Pageviews=". $_SESSION['type'];
   echo "Pageviews=". $_SESSION['no'];
       header('Location:menu.php');
```

### menu.php

```
  <?php sesstion_start();
  echo "Pageviews=". $_SESSION['type'];
  echo "Pageviews=". $_SESSION['no'];
  ?>
```

Comment: Change this `$_SESSIONE['no']=$no;` to `$_SESSION['no']=$no;`

Comment: You had an "E" in `$_SESSIONE['no']=$no;`. change it and try it again. Plus try setting your `session_start();` on top.

Comment: This is not problem by why are you putting unneccessary double quotes around variables when setting `$type` and `$no`?  You should also reference indexes properly like this:  `$type=$info['TYPE']`

Comment: **TYPO**, again? Change `<?php sesstion_start();` to `<?php session_start();`. You had a `t` in there. See my updated answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've got a typo

```
   $_SESSIONE['no']=$no;
```

should be
       $_SESSION['no']=$no;

Comment: if u want to mark this answer as the question's answer, click on the tick mark under the vote sign to mark it as answer

Comment: @user2629839 How can this be the accepted answer? Your code is riddled with errors. Have you not seen my answer?

Comment: I think $_SESSION was the problem

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT:** IMO, the OP accepted the wrong answer.

```
IMO="In My Opinion";
```

I knew the OP would have returned to post a [**NEW QUESTION**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17953570/session-variable-not-displayed-in-another-page).

Here is the work that I've put in below.

---

**NOTE**: This answer is in regards to the OP's original posted code as well as the edited version.

**Unless this is not a "TYPO",** then the following should be corrected as follows.

You have an "**E**" in `$_SESSIONE['no']=$no;`

Change this line:

```
$_SESSIONE['no']=$no; 
         ^
         E < error
```

to:

```
$_SESSION['no']=$no;
```

Plus try setting your `session_start();` on top of `$info = mysql_fetch_array( $data );`

**Your edited question (as of 9 minutes ago) contains new errors:**

Change `<?php sesstion_start();` to `<?php session_start();`. You had a `t` in there.

```
                 ^ (t)
```

**And if I may quote ["Mike Brant"](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1529853/mike-brant) :**

*"This is not problem by why are you putting unneccessary double quotes around variables when setting `$type` and `$no`? You should also reference indexes properly like this: `$type=$info['TYPE']`*"

I think what Mike Brant was trying to say was to:

change `$type="$info[TYPE]";` to `$type=$info[TYPE];`

and `$no="$info[NO]";` to `$no=$info[NO];` thus removing the `"`.

Comment: @user2629839 I don't understand exactly what it is that you mean. I think what Mike Brant was trying to say is to change `$type="$info[TYPE]";` to `$type=$info[TYPE];` and `$no="$info[NO]";` to `$no=$info[NO];` thus removing the `"`, if that's what you mean.

Comment: @user2629839 Go over my answer carefully, and you will see where you had errors. And I hope they were not typos on your part.

Comment: @user2629839 IMO, you accepted the wrong answer. Your code has far more errors than the answer you accepted as the correct one. Click the checkmark to accept, otherwise I will delete my answer.

Comment: `change $type="$info[TYPE]"; to $type=$info[TYPE];`
`"$info[TYPE]"` is perfectly valid. Are you aware that u can reference variables inside strings in php. Also you don't need to surround the key with quotes if it is already inside a string. 
Also shifting session_start before the mysql statement is pointless since $info = mysql_fetch_array( $data ); does not output any data to buffer nor does print any headers. There is no difference between the two.learn to be respectful.

Comment: @SomeshMukherjee Sure, I can accept that, however there were other errors in the OP's code that I pointed out, which you did not. No big deal, I won't lose any sleep over it. I merely wanted to point out that I had corrected **"ALL*"* of the errors and not just some.

Comment: @user2629839 (added note) Have you not seen my [**comment above**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17953009/php-session-displaying-the-error-message/17953065?noredirect=1#comment26238752_17953009) as well as in my answer? `(menu.php)` - You will see why now, why the OP accepted the wrong answer. If someone else finds this question and is looking for answers, well.... it won't be the correct answer, now will it? (wink)

Comment: @user2629839 Oh, and guess what. If you look closely in my answer, you will notice I mentioned that the OP went and asked another question **after** he accepted your answer, because of the error he/she made in **menu.php** which you did not point out `<?php sesstion_start();` [**Click here**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17953570/session-variable-not-displayed-in-another-page) to see the other question posted, and you will see that I was correct. (**wink**)

Comment: if you see the revison history of the question, he made that edit sessiont_start after i answered the question. So until that point, the answer was valid. None of the other errors you pointed out were actually errors. Good practice, sure. but not errors. anyways, peace

Comment: @SomeshMukherjee Yes I agree with what you said, **100%**. My comments were not aimed at you, but towards the OP. You did what you had to do, and so did I, Your answer was indeed valid, as so mine was. It's only to provide a correct answer for the final result; if and when someone else happens to visit the OP's question in order to look for answers. *Peace to you as well Somesh.*