# Session variable not displayed in another page

Tags: php, html, session, session-variables

i am using two webpage in menu.php i am not able to get the detail of session variable it will display undefined index.

### controller.php

```
    $info = mysql_fetch_array( $data );  
   session_start();
   // store session data
   $type="$info[TYPE]";
   $no="$info[NO]";

   $_SESSION['type']=$type;
   $_SESSION['no']=$no;
   echo "Pageviews=". $_SESSION['type'];
   echo "Pageviews=". $_SESSION['no'];
   header('Location:menu.php');
```

### menu.php

```
    <?php sesstion_start();
     echo "Pageviews=". $_SESSION['type'];
    echo "Pageviews=". $_SESSION['no'];
    ?>
```

Answer (score 6):

`sesstion_start();`

See anything wrong in here? :P

Comment: @MightyPork +1 for answering first, and mentioning "I was first."

Comment: @MightyPork, I've deleted my answer :)